# We just hit another milestone!

Tags: discussion

So, our site just hit another milestone. **We are over 10 questions per day**, which means we're increasing in traffic and volume. (Kudos to the mods too!)

[You can view the stats here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science). We also have very impressive other stats too.

The only orange and red areas are the number of unanswered questions, and the answers per question stats.

For improving the `the number of unanswered questions` stat, do go through the [unanswered posts tab](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and start answering whichever you can.

For improving the `answers per question stats`, do post answers for questions (doesn't matter if they're answered or not) which you think you have a better answer to, and which can help the OP further, building up on the info. provided by the current answers.

So, **congrats on the milestone**, and happy data wrangling!

Comment: Among these questions I wonder how many would be on-topic on stats Stack Exchange.

Comment: Actually, the answer rate and unanswered questions list is the toughest one on the Area51 stats.